# PHP Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Tags: php, mysql

Возникает ошибка

> PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /home/u20806/public_html/strangeip.php on line 34

Вот эти строки:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["session_username2"])) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='" . $_SESSION["session_username2"] . "'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        print_r($row);
        $query = $row['email'];
    }
}
```

Данный код возвращает массив типа

> Array ( [id] => 1 [email] => blabla [username] => admin [password] => 1234 [time] => 1452114053 [ip] => 127.0.0.1 )

$query выдает

> Resource id #6

Однако $row:

> Array ( [id] => 1 [email] => blabla [username] => admin [password] => 1234 [time] => 1452114053 [ip] => 127.0.0.1 )

Comment: не используйте msql - Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL.  что касается ошибки - проверяйте результат запроса. у вас скорее всего, вернулся false

Comment: Дополню, что вернуться мог еще и null, поэтому нужно проверять еще и количество возвращаемых записей, помимо успешности самого запроса.

Comment: @VenZell `mysql_fetch_assoc` может вернуть `NULL`? При каких условиях?

Comment: Только `mysql_query`. Насколько помню при пустой выборке, когда нет записей. Сейчас проверить нет возможности. Мог и напутать.

Comment: @VenZell Если нет записей, все равно возвращается `resource`, только первый же `mysql_fetch_assoc()` вернет `FALSE`. Но не переживайте, эта информация уже врядли пригодится :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
function row($session_username2) {
    $data = array();
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username=$session_username2"));
    return $data;
}
if (isset($_SESSION["session_username2"])) {
   $row = row($_SESSION["session_username2"]);
   echo $row['email'];
}
```

Comment: Не надо так делать: 1. `$data = array();` ненужная строка; 2. вы вызваете `mysql_fetch_assoc()` без проверки результата `mysql_query()`, который может вернуть `FALSE` и скрипт "упадет"; 3. `mysql_fetch_assoc()` может вернуть `FALSE` и `echo $row['email'];` вызовет ошибку; 4. вы оформили в функцию необоснованно маленький кусочек; 5. все решение никак не объяснено. Минус __не мой__

Comment: @tutankhamun я просто сделал пример автор вопроса решает правильно или неправильно. Автор вопроса решил так не знаю...

Comment: Я не пытаюсь добиться отмены решения топикстартера и не ждал от вас оправданий, каждый имеет право на свое мнение, но ваше решение не выдерживает критики. Все обоснования я привел, если не согласны, можем обсудить (желательно в чате)

Answer (score 3):

Наверняка ошибка в запросе и `mysql_query` возвращает `FALSE`. Смотрите в `error_log` веб-сервера.

**Обновлено**

*Слона-то я и не приметил*. Ваша основная ошибка в том, что вы присваиваете переменной `$query` строковое значение (`$query = $row['email'];`). Поэтому при следующем шаге цикла в `mysql_fetch_assoc()` попадает строковое значение, что вызывает ошибку.

Однако в целом не очень хорошо так делать:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["session_username2"])) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username='" . $_SESSION["session_username2"] . "'");
    /* Вставлять переменные в запрос без предварительной
       фильтрации и экранирования данных чревато ошибками
       и SQL-инъекциями. */
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        /* Брать данные в цикле наверное не очень правильно, что-то
           мне кажется что вы ожидаете параметры для одного пользователя */
        print_r($row);
        $query = $row['email'];
        /* Ну и наконец вот это и есть причина проблемы, которую вы
           обозначили в вопросе */
    }
}
```

Также как вам подскаывает @splash58 расширение `php_mysql` устарело и в следующих версиях будет удалено.

Вот вам пример того, как стОит сделать, если вы не хотите *пока* переходить с `php_mysql`:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["session_username2"])) {
    $safeUserName = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["session_username2"]);
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE username="' . $safeUserName . '"');
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $userMail = $row['email'];
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Not found user: ' . $safeUserName, MY_ERR_NOT_FOUND_USER);
        /* Пользуйтесь исключениями - это хорошая практика.
           Просто поверьте :) */
    }
    /* Еще можно проверить количество возвращенных строк, если их
       больше чем одна, то эту ситуацию тоже стОит рассмотреть отдельно */ 
}
```